# Java visitor pattern when type of visitor depends on type of visitee

Tags: java, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I'm trying to figure out the correct approach (and pattern) that my current problem requires. Everything seems to lead me towards the visitor pattern, and wikipedia's [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is almost exactly what I need. However, my issue is that I'm retrieving these `CarElement`s from the database and need to create the correct visitor depending on the type of `CarElement`s I asked for. For example, if I retrieved a list of `Windshield`s I want to pass in a `CarElementWashVisitor`. It feels like I'm going against the pattern here but I'm not sure what the correct approach is without checking the subclass type. I basically need some way to figure out what to do based on the runtime type of the object(s). Here's a summarized portion of the wikipedia example that I linked to above:

```
interface CarElementVisitor {
    void visit(Wheel wheel);
    void visit(Engine engine);
    void visit(Body body);
    void visit(Car car);
}

interface CarElement {
    void accept(CarElementVisitor visitor); // CarElements have to provide accept().
}

class CarElementPrintVisitor implements CarElementVisitor { /**/ }

class CarElementDoVisitor implements CarElementVisitor { /**/ }
```

**UPDATE:**

Turns out that the issue is actually pretty simple (as illustrated by the accepted answer below). Here's what I was looking for:

```
class MyVisitor implements CarElementVisitor {
    private MyService carwashService;

    /* visit(Wheel w), visit(Engine e)... etc */

    void visit(Windshield w) {
        carwashService.wash(w);
    }
}
```

Comment: if the visitor was unique, you could store that as a static value in each car element class. but it looks like it's not since a windshield could be visited by a print visitor also. so perhaps each concrete visitor class has a set of allowed concrete visitors or vice versa.

is the wash visitor a subclass of the do visitor?

Comment: Correct, the visitor is actually a Spring-injected component. Doesn't necessarily have to be a subclass of the DoVisitor, just needs to implement `CarElementVisitor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this help?

```
class FindTheRightVisitorVisitor implements CarElementVisitor {
    private CarElementVisitor theVisitor;
    ... getter etc ...
    void visit(Windshield w) {
        if (theVisitors == null) {
            theVisitors = new CarElementWashVisitor();
        }
    }
}
```

And use here:

```
CarElement root = ...;
CarElementVisitor findIt = new FindTheRightVisitorVisitor();
root.accept(findIt);
CarElementVisitor theRightVisitor = findIt.getTheVisitor();
root.accept(theRightVisitor);
```

Comment: Yeah, this is actually more than what I need, I realized that I simply need to just have 1 visitor (with methods for each type), and that visitor calls or delegates to the actual logic because it knows which service to call at that point. Thanks!